# What does ':' mean in React.js?

Tags: javascript, syntax

It is confusing to me that `=` seems to assign values to variables as it usually does in other languages, but what does `:` do?

I feel like it is assigning functions or some other stuff to a variable.

What exactly it is doing?

Here is an example:

```
import React from 'react';

const MyComponents = {
  DatePicker: function DatePicker(props) {
    return <div>Imagine a {props.color} datepicker here.</div>;
  }
}

function BlueDatePicker() {
  return <MyComponents.DatePicker color="blue" />;
}
```

The colon is after `DatePicker`

Comment: That colon is actually unrelated to React itself. It's a (rather cool) built in feature of Javascript!

Comment: This has nothing to do with react. This is plain old javascript [object initialiazer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) I do recommend you to read some basic js tutorial before deep diving into react or any other lib.

Comment: Learn the basics of JavaScript before learning ReactJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know react but I'm pretty sure this is just standard javascript syntax for defining methods in objects. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_methods

```
objectName.methodname = function_name;

var myObj = {
  myMethod: function(params) {
    // ...do something
  }

  // OR THIS WORKS TOO

  myOtherMethod(params) {
    // ...do something else
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I will check the JS doc.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much a react.js thing as it is a JSON thing. JSON is the JavaScript Object Notation. Here `:` is used within `{}` to assign properties to the object. `MyComponents` becomes an object and you can access properties as `MyComponents.DatePicker`.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't anything React specific. That is just saying that `MyComponents` is an object and `DatePicker` is one of it's values.

It's no different from defining a normal object:

```
const food = {
    apple: 'Apple',
    banana: 'Banana'
};
```